# How to get a "pour" effect

Tags: effects, paint.net

I am trying to manipulate an image so that it looks like it is being poured out of a jug as a stream. Unfortunately I don't have access to Photoshop, but I do have paint.net. I got fairly far with the Twist distortion along with stretching it along the X axis, but still not quite right.

Can somebody make a recommendation on how to make such an image?

Comment: I would suggest that this kind of effect is best achieved in a 3D modelling package. It could be done in Photoshop, but it would not be a trivial task. I doubt that paint has advanced enough tools for something like this.

Comment: I would use Illustrator Envelope Distort.  Illustrator is available free on a 30 day trial basis. I highly recommend you familiarize yourself with it. With Envelope Distort you can fit a shape into another shape. So make the shape of the pour and then use envelope distort to squeeze the image into it.

Answer (score 1):

Options:

1. Define what kind of liquid you need, mainly transparent or non transparent and viscosity.
2. If it's for a comercial project, find a stock image suitable to your project.

   - You probably need to find separated images for the liquid and for the jar.
3. Mask and cut the liquid, rotate if necesary.
4. Mask and cut the jar.

The problem is that Paint.net will not work for you.

Use Gimp that has a tool you will need. It's called Warp and you can find it under

```
Menu > Filters > Distort I Warp
```

This is to modify the curvature to fit your dimensions.

---

But Chris' comment is true.

Nowadays a lof of this kind of images are computer simulations, or **CGI** Computer Generated Images . Blender https://www.blender.org/ is a great option.

Look for a Blender liquid tutorial like this one for example https://www.google.com/search?q=blender+liquid+tutorial